# Multiple Comparisons test strategy

Tags: anova, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons

I have a test data with `3452 subjects` , I have `5 different algorithms` that detect the presence or absence of a disease.

```
Algorithm 1 identified 100 diseased subjects
Algorithm 2 identified 233 diseased subjects
Algorithm 3 identified 539 diseased subjects
Algorithm 4 identified 213 diseased subjects
Algorithm 5 identified 725 diseased subjects
```

What multiple comparison statistical test should I perform if my goal is to test if these results are statistically different  from each other ? I dont have the standard deviation values, I just ran these 5 algorithms on the test dataset once and (n=3452) and thats it, if I ran these algorithms again I would get the same results. Any advise on this situation is much appreciated..

Comment: Is your question whether given that (a) these subjects are a completely representative sample of the population to which these tests would be applied, (b) the population the tests would be applied to is very large (i.e. >>3452), can the higher disease diagnosis for some subjects due to chance (e.g. the subjects included in the sample) or would we expect some of these to always give a higher percentage of positive diagnoses (whether correctly or incorrectly)?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, each of the 5 algorithms is run on the same data set of 3452. Each algorithm is deterministic, so for any given dataset, once you produce the numbers above, you are done. You don't need a test -- the numbers are different (is that difference meaningful?, Is one number closer to known truth?)

Maybe you are asking something more along the lines of: "Do these algorithms consistently produce different results across distinct data sets, and is that difference `significant'?"

One way to inject some randomness back into the problem (without knowing much more about your setup) is to take 100 samples with replacement of your dataset, run all 5 algorithms on each sample, and make 5 boxplots, each containing the 100 numbers from running the algorithm on the sample.

By sampling, you are generating a dataset that you could have observed, across a large number of such datasets you see the distribution of results from any given algorithm. After such a procedure, one might then test if the distributions have common mean, or might do something even simpler, like make a plot and look to see how overlapping they are.